# How to avoid loop inside loop

Tags: php, algorithm, logic

I have this code:

```
foreach($categories as $category) {
  $items = getItems($category);

  foreach($items as $item) {
     // some code to manipulate $item
  }
}
```

As you can see, inner loop depends on outer loop. Problem is that if data is too big, this takes quite some time. Is there some way, algorithm or technique so that I can *avoid inner loop* that is dependent on outer loop ?

PS. I am using PHP 5.3 so `yield` is out of question. Also someone told me that may be recursion can be helpful here but I don't exactly know how to go about with that.

Thanks for the help

Comment: With what you've provided, I can't see any way to algorithmically avoid this.  You can possibly tweak the _workflow_ of what you're trying to do so that you don't have to manipulate the items of every category at once and instead just do a single category at a time

Comment: Does getItems run a database query?

Comment: If you can put your array code and what you expected as an output then anyone can suggest  the solution

Comment: please add `getItems`'s code

Comment: Overall my point is how to avoid loop inside loop, it does not matter if I am using database or what `getItems` does. This is often the case when we have to write such code but there should be some better performant way to  may be avoid inner loop. hope makes sense.

Comment: not make sense. it depends on the case. what's your desired output. Some time same output can get without inner loop and some time it's necessary.

Comment: I agree with other.  Changing your coding style to "functional" is not guaranteed/likely to improve performance.  We, of course, cannot say with absolute certainty because we have NO IDEA what `getItems()` does.  If performance is a problem, then it is likely that a code refactor is warranted.  We don't have a [mcve]. I've voting to close this question as Unclear (or others may prefer Needs Debugging Details).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to avoid the nested loops is to store the data first, an then manipulate it

```
$items=array_map("getItems",$categories);
$items=array_reduce("array_merge",$items);
array_walk($items,"item_manipulation");
```

Note that this code is not more efficient than your original snippet, it's just without nested loops as you asked.

A more intelligent optimization would be (maybe) possible if we could know what `getItems` does, and what per-item manipulation you do